# How can i make iBeacons private

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, ibeacon

I created an App which is using some iBeacons functionalities. The goal is to add some beacons in some clients stores so the App shows notifications specific for this stores.Now i am using an UUID that is the same for all my beacons and I am managing to identify the store using minor and major values.

How can I make the beacons not accessible by other Apps ? Is there a way to add passwords to beacons or something like this ?

Answer (score 3):

Ok after looking in Estimotes websites i found out that there is a way to lock your beacons.

http://blog.estimote.com/post/103051450215/delivering-on-the-promise-of-beacons-a-modular

To wrap it up: There is a thing called secureUUID. This uuid is changing every couple of minutes. To be able to track this uuid you have to use Estimote cloud service so you can synchronise your app region tracking with beacon.

Comment: Hi Chris, this is Wojtek from Estimote. That's right, this is basically what our Secure UUID does: it rotates the beacons ID in such a way that only Estimote Cloud can resolve the real ID. If you're looking for details on implementing that in your app, it's described here: https://community.estimote.com/hc/en-us/articles/204233603-How-security-feature-works

Also, keep in mind that iBeacon as a standard does not offer any security measures. Different vendors offer different security methods for preventing piggybacking, spoofing, and unauthorized access to beacons.

Comment: wow! Thanks Wojtek. Is there a way to use secure uuid without Estimote Cloud ?

Comment: unfortunately no. The key to resolving beacon's real ID is retrieved from Estimote Cloud. It doesn't add almost any additional elements to the development itself (you only need to sign up and get your API token from Estimote Cloud's web dashboard), but does require internet connection on the user's end.

Cheers.

Comment: So the device needs internet to get the correct uuid ?

Comment: Yup, it needs to fetch the real ID from the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible,iBeacons use very small package size on Bluetooth just sending the UUID and major/minor identifiers.

This has a draw back that you might fake a iBeacon if you know their UUID.